# Push content with css translate

Tags: css, css-transforms

Does anyone know a way to push the content according to an element css translation?

This example will be way more talkative (also available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLVXZE)):

```css
.d0 {
  display: flex;
}

.d1,
.d2,
.d3 {
  background-color: #ad3;
  height: 100px;
}

.d1 {
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 300px;
}

.d2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}

.d3 {
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

 :checked+div .d1 {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

 :checked+div .d3 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle">Check to animate translateX</label>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<div class="d0">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
<label for="toggle2">Check to animate width</label>
<input id="toggle2" type="checkbox" />
<div class="d0">
  <div class="d3"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

We can see that animating width works as expected, but we know that using CSS transformations is way smoother. And in my real case I have way more content to animate so the difference is visible.
Also I cannot use the scale transformation because my content would be distorted.

Comment: what do you mean by `I have way more content to animate so the difference is visible`?

Comment: I mean that the width animation is not very smooth

Comment: The exact reason why translate is more efficient is just because of this, It doesn't trigger a reflow. If you could achieve a translate **with** reflow, it would be also sluggish

Comment: @vals That's not true. I tested it out myself. For example, he could still use "translate" and trigger reflow at the same time by putting a placeholder sibling the same `padding-left` or `padding-right` as the element width, with that element's position set to `absolute`. Then on animation, he could both trigger the padding transition on the placeholder sibling and also trigger translate transition on the main element; both transition have the same timings so it appears as if the translate is the one pushing. I just did it and achieved the same effect but much much less sluggish and smoother.

Comment: Basically, it seems that this illusive/hacky technique of using an empty sibling div and transitioning its own padding while translating your absolute-position heavy content element at the same time saves a lot of performance and makes everything look much better.